# Can't connect to WPA2/PEAP/MSCHAPv2 enterprise wifi network without a certificate. Fedora 34

Tags: fedora, wifi, networkmanager, iwlwifi, wpa

My university wifi uses WPA2 Enterprise for students to connect with their logins and passwords and I cannot do it, network manager always says the password is incorrect and prompts me for another one even though the password is correct.

My problem is simmiliar to https://askubuntu.com/questions/279762/how-to-connect-to-wpa2-peap-mschapv2-enterprise-wifi-networks-that-dont-use-a-c but none of the solutions work for me. I use Fedora 34 Gnome, my wifi adapter model is Intel AX200

My `/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/UNIVERSITY.WIFI` look like this

```
[connection]
id=UNIVERSITY.WIFI
uuid=0cdeb50f-03dd-45ba-85df-465027f0e12a
type=wifi
interface-name=wlp1s0
permissions=

[wifi]
hidden=true
mac-address-blacklist=
mode=infrastructure
ssid=UNIVERSITY.WFIFI
[wifi-security]
key-mgmt=wpa-eap

[802-1x]
eap=peap;
identity=my_login
password=my_password
phase2-auth=mschapv2

[ipv4]
dns-search=
method=auto

[ipv6]
addr-gen-mode=stable-privacy
dns-search=
method=auto

[proxy]
```

Answer (score 1):

[Here's](https://www.reddit.com/r/Fedora/comments/jd92gb/wpa2_enterprise_network_no_longer_works_after/) your answer:

> Looks like after setting the phase 2 crypto settings with:
>
> ```
> update-crypto-policies --set LEGACY
> ```
>
> as indicated here: I was able to connect with no issues.

> Your TLS certificate probably uses either SHA-1 (most likely) or RSA-1028 (less likely). Both are rejected now.
>
> Test by downgrading your system policy to allow all crypto that was permitted in Fedora 32:
>
> ```
> $ sudo dnf install crypto-policies-scripts
> $ sudo update-crypto-policies --set DEFAULT:FEDORA32
> ```
>
> If my guess is wrong, you'll want to revert to secure Fedora 33 default > settings:
>
> ```
> $ sudo update-crypto-policies --set DEFAULT
> ```

TL;DR:

```
sudo update-crypto-policies --set LEGACY
```